# why is this PHP script failing when i replace this

Tags: php, html

I have a checkbox, that originally had a value attached to it.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_style" name="facebook" id="facebook" value="yes"/>
```

I had original php handler set as

```
if ($_POST['facebook'] = "yes") {

    $facebook = "yes";
}

else {

    $facebook = "no";
}
```

I  have now taken the value away from the checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_style" name="facebook" id="facebook"/>
```

and have tried to replace the handler with this

```
if !isset($_POST['facebook']) {

    $facebook = "no";
}

else {

    $facebook = "yes";
}
```

But as soon as I do the page fails and there is no error (like it's a syntax error).

Can anyone tell me why this is failing please?

Comment: $_POST variable cant hold "id" DOM element after submission

Comment: `$_POST['facebook'] = "yes"` It is an assignment!

Comment: what should I do, instead then please @Aviz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you're doing an assignment with

```
if ($_POST['facebook'] = "yes")
                       ^
```

and will always be TRUE and equaling "yes".

It should contain 2x equal signs for comparison.

```
if ($_POST['facebook'] == "yes")
                       ^^
```

then

```
if !isset($_POST['facebook'])
```

is missing 2x brackets

```
if( !isset($_POST['facebook']) )
```

---

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

---

**Footnotes:**

> *"I have now taken the value away from the checkbox"*

Should you want to use that again later on, you may find it will be better for you to incorporate your entire conditional statement into one:

```
if (isset($_POST['facebook']) && $_POST['facebook'] == "yes")
```

- This would be beneficial in using a radio button group, where a user would have the choice between yes or no.
- It's an option.

Example radio buttons:

```
Yes: 
<input type="radio" name="facebook" value="yes"/>
No: 
<input type="radio" name="facebook" value="no"/>

 // 

if (isset($_POST['facebook']) && $_POST['facebook'] == "yes")
 { echo "Yes chosen"; }

if (isset($_POST['facebook']) && $_POST['facebook'] == "no")
 { echo "No chosen"; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you forget `(` before `if` and `)` after `$_POST['facebook'])`  maybe,This line:

```
if (!isset($_POST['facebook'])) {
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Will mark as correct in 7 mins. Always the small things that get me!

Comment: This isn't entirely true; there's something missing here. Look at this very carefully.

Comment: @SpringheeledJack This answer does not cover all of your errors! Are you sure that this answer was the most helpful one for you and solved your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ternary operator:

```
$facebook = isset($_POST['facebook']) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

---

- Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php